# Use MATLAB function handles to reference original matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, reference

I often have to manipulate a lot of matrices row by row using MATLAB.

Instead of having to type:

```
m(x, :);
```

every time I want to reference a particular row, I created an [anonymous MATLAB function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html):

```
row = @(x) m(x, :);
```

allowing me to call `row(x)` and get the correct row back.

But it seems that this anonymous function is actually not the same as calling `m(x, :)` directly, as the reference to the matrix is lost. So when I call something like:

```
row(2) = 2 * row(2);
```

MATLAB returns the error:

> error: can't perform indexed assignment for function handle type
>
> error: assignment failed, or no method for 'function handle = matrix'

Is there a way to define a function handle to get around this problem, or am I better off just typing out `m(x, :)` when I want to reference a row?

Thanks so much!

Comment: typing out `m(x,:)` is less typing and therefore neater in your code. Why would you want to do this in an anonymous function?

Comment: An anonymous function is cleaner in my opinion and more human-readable.

Comment: Are you trying to do elementary row operations?

Comment: Yes, elementary row operations is the end application for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*reference* through a handle only work for Matlab `object/class` inherited from the `handle` class.

If as you said in comment "*elementary row operations is the end application for this*", then David's answer is a good simple way to go (or simply keep using `m(x,:)` which is still the shortest syntax after all).

If you really want to venture into `handles` and true *reference* values, then you can create a class `rowClass` which you specialise in *row* operations. An example with a few *row* operations would be:

```
classdef rowClass < handle

    properties
        m = [] ;
    end

    methods
        %// constructor
        function obj = rowClass(matrix)
            obj.m = matrix ;
        end

        %// row operations on a single row ----------------------------
        function obj = rowinc(obj,irow,val)
            %// increment values of row "irow" by scalar (or vector) "val"
            obj.m(irow,:) = obj.m(irow,:) + val ;
        end

        function obj = rowmult(obj,irow,val)
            %// multiply by a scalar or by a vector element wise 
            obj.m(irow,:) = obj.m(irow,:) .* val ; 
        end

        function obj = rowsquare(obj,irow)
            %// multiply the row by itself
            obj.m(irow,:) = obj.m(irow,:).^2 ; 
        end

        %// row operations between two rows ---------------------------
        function obj = addrows(obj,irow,jrow)
            %// add values of row "jrow" to row "irow"
            obj.m(irow,:) = obj.m(irow,:) + obj.m(jrow,:) ;
        end

        function obj = swaprows(obj,irow,jrow)
            %// swap rows 
            obj.m([irow,jrow],:) = obj.m([jrow,irow],:) ;
        end
    end
end
```

Of course you could add all the operations you frequently do to your rows, or even to the full matrix (or a subset).

---

Example usage:

```
%% // sample data
A = (1:5).' * ones(1,5) ;  %'// initial matrix
B = rowClass( A ) ;        %// make an object out of it

B = 
  rowClass with properties:

    m: [5x5 double]

B.m %// display the matrix
ans =
     1     1     1     1     1
     2     2     2     2     2
     3     3     3     3     3
     4     4     4     4     4
     5     5     5     5     5
```

Add a value (12) to all elements of the row(1):

```
%% // add a value (scalar or vector) to a row
rowinc(B,1,12) ;
B.m
ans =
    13    13    13    13    13
     2     2     2     2     2
     3     3     3     3     3
     4     4     4     4     4
     5     5     5     5     5
```

Square the row(3):

```
%% // Square row 3
rowsquare(B,3) ;
B.m
ans =
    13    13    13    13    13
     2     2     2     2     2
     9     9     9     9     9
     4     4     4     4     4
     5     5     5     5     5
```

Last one for the road, swap row(3) and row(5):

```
%% // swap rows
swaprows(B,5,3) ; 
B.m
ans =
    13    13    13    13    13
     2     2     2     2     2
     5     5     5     5     5
     4     4     4     4     4
     9     9     9     9     9
```

Answer (score 3):

By defining an anonymous function, you make every row immutable (at least through row). Reassigning the value of a function handle is simply not possible.

Imagine that you define the function handle `mySquare(x) = @(x) x.^2 ;`. If reassigning the output of a function handle would be possible, you could change the value of `mySquare(2)` (e.g., `mySquare(2)=2`) and basically states that `4=2`!

On the positive side, your anonymous function "protects" your initial input `m` from unexpected modifications. If you want to use your function `row`, you should simply define another matrix `m_prime`, whose rows are initialized with the function handle `row` (avoid using `m` again since it would probably mix everything up).

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll be best off typing `m(x,:)`! It's not much quicker than doing `row(x)`. Another issue with the anonymous function `row` is that it will keep the original matrix `m`, which wont change.

Here is an anonymous function that does what you want, I think it's a reasonable way of doing things. `row(a,b,c)` multiplies the `b`'th row of the matrix (not necessarily square) `a` by `c`.

```
x=rand(5)
row=@(x,i,k) (diag([ones(1,i-1) k ones(1,size(x,1)-(i))]))*x
x=row(x,2,20)
```

Ultimately, I think the simplest method is to make a standalone function to do each type of row operation. For example,

```
function x=scalarmult(x,i,k)
x(i,:)=k*x(i,:);
```

and

```
function x=addrows(x,i,j)
x(i,:)=x(i,:)+x(j,:);
```

and

```
function x=swaprows(x,i,j)
x([i,j],:)=x([j,i],:);
```